# Editing text in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, editing

I have a project in Premier Pro.

I added lot of text and clips to my timeline and when I have returned to it the next day I can't seem to find a way to edit the text anymore, all I am seeing is yellow and red line on top of the timeline indicating where the text starts and ends but no way of actually grabbing it to edit it.

Comment: Could the font have gone missing somehow?  If you used a normal system font, this would be unlikely, but if you downloaded something, then... maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Try Selecting your Text Tool... the Capital "T" in the tool bar. Using that Click or double Click on the text you want to edit. That should get you there.